# What replaced file owner?

Tags: xcode, xib

I am following an xcode tutorial mentioning file owner in relation to a xib. I understand that this is an old tutorial but I still want to follow it. "Select the ViewController.xib window, and then File's Owner." What could this refer to in xcode 7?

Comment: It still exists in XCode 7. Open the xib, on the left panel, there is a section named `PlaceHolder`, here it is. You can `Show Document Outline` if not clearly visible. Else, you may have to add a screenshot to be sure that you don't have it.

Comment: I don't think I have a xib (I haven't declared one)

Comment: If you don't have a Xib, that's a whole new story. `File/New File/User Interface/` and select the one you want, Empty for example, and then add a UIViewController.

Comment: I have edited main storyboard and nothing else. Does that count as a xib